# Laravel 8 - Getting randomly "No application encryption key has been specified"

Tags: php, laravel, rest, caching

**Please try to read & answer to the question asked, instead of suggesting improvements to public-routing which isn't there by an accident.**

---

**Edit #5 (updated @ 20.10.2021)** Unfortunately the question remains unanswered. I'm really baffled by this, but even more so, **this error hasn't been showing up for past few days, and I have no idea what happened.**

I used to have custom static "User::hasRole(['...']"-method which fetched users userRoles everytime roles were checked. Biggest change I made was caching user-roles to session, so that there wouldn't be need to fetch 'em every time (as dozens of rest-queries were referring to checking roles from DB over and over again as part of querybuilders filters).

```
$userRoles = Session()->get('userRoles', function() {
    $user = User::with(['userRoles'])->find(Auth::user()->id);
    Session()->put('userRoles', $user->userRoles);
    return $user->userRoles;
});
```

I know this solution could cause an issue at certain points, but due to the nature of my project it's almost nonexistent risk.

These random errors never seemed to point to one specific method and nothing pointed this direction. It looks like this error will remain somewhat a mystery, but at the time being it's not causing issues anymore. Best I can guess is that there were too many parallel PHP/SQL-threads, which somehow lead to kernel pipeline failing at random states when authentication somehow failed.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.

**Edit #4 (updated @ 14.9.2021) Changing cache driver from file to array didn't resolve issue. Single endpoint just returned "unauthenticated"-message, even though user is authenticated.**

**Edit #3, Problem persists, trying to sum up:**

- Key HAS BEEN generated, even regenerated multiple times
- Laravel 8, XAMPP
- Have run config:cache multiple times. If config-cache has been cleared the problem happens more often, but currently maybe 1/100-200 REST calls end up failing more or less randomly. This doesn't happen on LAMP production-server.
- This problem causes randomly different errors, all somehow related to user session
- No application encryption key
- 401 - unauthenticated
- SQL Connection error (even though either refreshing page / rerunning post works like a charm, and only 1 of ~20 REST-actions on single page load might end up to this state).
- Doesn't seem to be CSRF-token related error since sessions are live (as other REST-calls are not failing), but for some reason Axios doesn't report XSRF-token on RESPONSE-headers whenever this error occurs. Token is present on REQUEST-headers... still looks like backend is unable to find session?
- Currently using file-based session handling, going to try memory-based

--

I'v been having an issue with Laravel producing HTTP code 500 - "No application encryption key has been specified" -error randomly on my rest-routes. **Of course I have set, and even reset the key with Artisan, so that shouldn't be the issue.**

This issue has always been present, ever since I started my project on Laravel 6. Quite quickly I was able to track issue to cache. Basically when cache was wiped with "php artisan cache:clear" REST-routes started to fail, about 5% of all the requests. When cache was generated again with "php artisan config:cache" the issue was resolved. For some reason it seems that .env -variables are not registered or read correctly when cache is wiped? Still, wasn't an issue when developing and cache was configured.

I'v upgraded my project from Laravel 6 to 8 and now it seems that this issue has started to reproduce and I'm unable to find the reason.

My application has ~10-20 initial atomic REST-endpoint accesses for providing basic information for Vue SPA initialization. All of these requests happen asynchronously and every-now-and-then (maybe once per 10 page refreshes / reinitializations) one of those calls might fail.

Running things over latest XAMPP. Not using XDebug or anything else which might block calls. Wondering if anyone else has stumbled to this problem?

**EDIT:**

Additionally I might get very random "401 - unauthenticated" -errors. The problem is very similar to application key -error. For an example this picture was taken after ~20 minutes activity on web-browser while jumping from one page to another. All the other calls before and after were behind authentication as well, but this single 401 came out of nowhere.

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Changing lottery-number didn't fix.

Comment: Check the errored routes to see if the error is a Laravel error or an error originating from the web-server. If it's a laravel error you might be able to put additional logging checkpoints in the middleware and routes (or even in vendor code temporarily just to see what's happening). Also you really should configure your server properly so it doesn't use `/public` for requests

Comment: It's an generic Laravel error with extremely long kerner stack. I'm also aware of public-routing, but this isn't an issue on my development server, as I have different masking on *nix server with .htaccess 

It could be an middleware-issue, but the problem is that failing routes seem to be random. Refreshing or recalling an route runs ok. It feels as if parallel calls would somehow "forget" or "unregister" authenticated user randomly

Comment: all laravel errors tend to have an extremely long kernel stack. Things to check with 401 errors (for stateful requests) usually include checking if the correct session cookie was sent, if the session was loaded correctly.

Comment: I believe you might be on to something. All the REST requests which go through have "set-cookie" with long value with "Response headers", such as "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpd ........", but whenever request fails it seems to be missing "set-cookie" -parameter.  Request -headers seem to have identical "Cookie"-parameter on both ok and failing requests. Would you have any pointers why this might happen?

I'm using Axios within Vue-side for those rest requests.

Comment: Honestly that is odd behaviour. The only reason that this would happen would be if the error occurred before the `StartSession` middleware has ran or that middleware (for some reason) failed to correctly start the session. This might happen if your session storing/retrieving mechanism is not 100% reliable but not sure if that is what is actually wrong here. As an experiment you can try switching your session storage driver to something else (like e.g. database or cookie if it was file previously) and see if that helps

Comment: @apokryfos, I added few pointers to original post (please see edit #2). I also suspect session-handler being a problem and somehow everything seems to be related to Windows XAMPP installation and/or session files.

Comment: What authentication method are you using? Are all routes under auth middleware? Can you post your session configuration? Does all request looks the same from access.log and chrome console (headers, encryption etc... )

Comment: @Mtxz session lifetime is 120, session_drive = file. It made no difference changing to memory-based session. Requests look same, except when session is "forgotten" (no app key, unauthenticated user etc error) it's missing csrf-keys. All are under auth-middleware, but PER route (not being grouped by function)

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden, Guards are default from 6.0. Apparently default is "web", which is using session-driver with providers = users

Comment: @Janne I'm a bit out of idea, as it appends randomly... Do you use somewhere in your code direct `env()` access without passing by an intermediate `config()` value maybe?

Comment: @Mtxz we both are :D .... No direct env-accesses. I believe things went south back in L5 or L6 when I was trying to implement some other authentication mode, such as passport. I'm bit out of ideas how to fix the problem, and it's even more annoying that the problem persists only on dev machine. I'm even thinking of moving local development to virtual machine LAMP

Comment: On Windows, you can also try the great 'Laragon" which I replaced wamp with a few years ago. You told me that "it's missing csrf-keys.", did you mean the request miss the CSRF token? And not the response?

Comment: Do you have correct permission on your project folder (recursive)? Have you tried running a script that loops on config('app.key') and echoes it during few minutes to see if you can reproduce it? Did you track the debug trace to the code line throwing the issue (in vendors certainly)?

Comment: @Mtxz Thanks for the tip on Laragon, will give it a try! Whenever rest fails it seems to be missing CSRF-token. I'm bit baffled by question on permissions as rest services answer 99% correctly, but that 1% is only failing. I haven't tracked failing calls well, because I don't have deep enough understanding on Laravel kernel-side pipeline. If I recall correctly it never reaches controller, but starts failing at bootstrap-part of Laravel. The idea of looping config isn't too bad, but I have an itch that this problem is related to multiple parallel REST-calls at same time.

Comment: So thus I should be able to reproduce problem by using setTimeout for promise.all(x,y,z) -rest calls

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden To my best knowledge, thats correct. They are behind auth-middleware on web.php

Comment: I really think the problem is your xampp server. You can try another app like laragon, wamp. I use the laragon all the times and laravel app running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Unfortunately this wasn't the solution. I thought that maybe sessions were mixing or something similar, but nope...**

I believe I finally found answer.

For previous Laravel version (5 & 6) it seems that problem was always with cache, as clearing it had resolved this problem, but moving from 6 -> 8 really brought this issue up.

I had different session-related problem at hand, which finally lead to detecting that something had changed on Laravel 8. My previous logout was

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

... but official documentation pointed out that it should be:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Apparently session needs to be manually invalidated, as well token being regenerated. I don't know the exact reason, but these two additional lines seemed to remove previous random errors. Most likely some old sessions were active and were brought up at random times on REST-API-routes.

I'll continue monitoring situation and will report if the problem persists, but as of now it looks like issue has been resolved.

Edit, additional details:

My LoginController contains logout-method, which is most likely an overwrite of "AuthenticatesUsers.php". The original method looks like following:

```
public function logout(Request $request) {
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    $request->session()->regenerateToken();

    if ($response = $this->loggedOut($request)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
        : redirect('/');
}
```

Basically keep using original logout-method or use comprehensive enough solution when overwriting. Can't really remember why I simplified this with more straight-forward overwriting method, but this was most likely the source of weird behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have defined the root of your application incorrectly.. configure your web-server so that the root is

```
/path/to/your/laravel/application/public
```

Note: **/public** at the end

Comment: Please read question before answering. Suggestion doesn't involve solution to asked question. Public routing on development server in this case is there by-choice, not accidentally, and to best of my knowledge doesn't have anything to do with issue described.